# Query String XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, rest, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I wrote a XSLT that will retrieve the query string from current URL and only show the item I want; the XSLT works like a charm. However, the page seems to stuck after the first load. The page itself is not doing any GET when I click any link in the navigation since they are technically "one page."

Is there a way I can use javascript to force the page really "reload"? (or to perform a call? to submit?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:param name="PageUrl"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@ID = substring-after($PageUrl,'=')]"/>     
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <div id="resources">
                <xsl:value-of select="@PublishingPageContent" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated.